# Word-topic matrix in Latent Dirichlet Allocation

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, latent-variable, topic-models

In the latent Dirichlet allocation model described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation), is $\beta$ the word-topic matrix?

I understand that $\beta$ is the topic-word matrix and that $\beta_{ij}$ contains the probability of word $i$ given topic $j$, but I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confusingly, the variables in Wikipedia's description of smoothed LDA don't follow the [paper introducing LDA](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/blei03a/blei03a.pdf). In the paper, $\beta$ is first described exactly as you've described it:

> ...the word probabilities are parameterized by a $k ×V$ matrix $\beta$ where $\beta_{ij} = p(w_j = 1|z_i = 1)$, which for now we treat as a fixed quantity that is to be estimated.

The authors later introduce smoothed LDA, in which each row of $\beta$ is drawn from an exchangeable Dirichlet with prior parameter $\eta$. Wikipedia presently uses $\beta$ where the paper uses $\eta$, and $\varphi$ where the paper uses $\beta$.

Here's the plate notation from the paper:

[image]

And from wiki:

[image]

I'm not sure which is more common in implementations. For example, [`scikit-learn`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.html) uses $\eta$ for the prior.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. The conventional meaning of $\beta$  (and it is used in the same sense in the Wikipedia article as of today) is a hyperparameter. It is concisely described in the Wikipedia article as

```
prior weight of word w in a topic; usually the same for all words; normally a number much less than 1, e.g. 0.001, to strongly prefer sparse word distributions, i.e. few words per topic
```

The thing you call word-topic matrix is given by $\phi_{kw}$ described as

```
probability of word w occurring in topic k
```